# Porque o compilador me alerta Anonymous new Runnable() can be replaced with lambda

Tags: java, android, android-studio, thread, warnings

Porque esse código (`Thread`) mostra essa mensagem (*no compilador*), e como fazer para que ele não mostre mais?

**Código:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    ...
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            (new Thread(new Runnable() { //(Anonymous new Runnable() can be replaced with lambda)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted() && isActive)
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //(Anonymous new Runnable() can be replaced with lambda)// start actions in UI thread
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Log.v("INFOS: THREAD", "Valor atribuido"); // this action have to be in UI thread
                                    }
                                });
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // ooops
                        }
                }
            })).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread
        }
    });
}
```

**Mensagem no compilador:**

> Anonymous new Runnable() can be replaced with lambda less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   This inspection reports all anonymous classes which can be replaced
>   with lambda expressions Lambda syntax is not supported under Java 1.7
>   or earlier JVMs.

Referência no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687011/run-loop-every-second-java).

**Como posso escrever esse código de forma que ele fique *correto***? O thread executa um comando a cada *x segundos* se *isActive* for *true*.

*Atenção para as tags da pergunta.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque no Java 8 temos a nova sintaxe de *lambda expressions* que visa simplificar a necessidade de (ab)usar de classes anônimas. Em especial, as classes anônimas que são implementações de interfaces com um único método (tal como `Runnable` que você usa duas vezes) podem ser simplificadas em forma de *lambda expressions*.

Assim fica o seu código com os lambdas, sem dúvida mais simples:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    ...
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            new Thread(() -> {
                while (!Thread.interrupted() && isActive) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Log.v("INFOS: THREAD", "Valor atribuido"));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // ooops
                    }
                }
            }).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread
        }
    });
}
```

Você não precisa se preocupar com essa *warning*. Você pode ignorá-la seguramente se quiser.

Na verdade essa *warning* é apenas uma dica de como você pode simplificar o seu código, **mas ela só é válida para Java 8 ou superior.** Ou dito de outra forma (tal como na mensagem), **não** é válida para Java 7 ou inferior.

E finalmente, o fato de você estar rodando uma thread com o loop não tem relação nenhuma com essa *warning*. O que a ocasiona é apenas o uso de classes anônimas que implementam `Runnable`.